# Project Smartphone Interface on tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

[here's what this is look like when I'm writting this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wW1ne.jpg)Hello I am currently in high school I have a project to render in computer science it is a project on a small smartphone style interface I managed to reproduce certain buttons but starting with tkinter it sometimes remains unclear... Currently I am looking for a way to add an image as background, find how to display in a small window on the interface and also to reorganize the buttons like a real phone, if anyone has any suggestions, I'm really interested. Thanks for reading.

```
import sys  # importation du modul sys permettant certaines choses
import webbrowser  # importation du module webbrowser permettant de se servir du navigateur depuis python

# initialisation de la variable interface qui sera une instance de l'objet tk du module tkinter permettant de crée rune interface graphoique
interface = Tk()

# défintion des dimensions de l'interface se rapprochant des dimensions d'un smartphone au 21 siècle
interface.geometry("325x600")
interface.title("SmartFace")
interface.iconbitmap("icons/smartphone-icon.ico")
wallpaper = "black"
interface.config(background=wallpaper)

# initialisation de focntion permettant d'acceder aux sites les plus utilisé et pouvant répondre aux attentes et besoins des utilisateur comme
# se divertir, communiquer faire des recherches etc


def google():
    """procédure permettant l'utilisation du module webbrowser pour accéder
    à l'URL saisi en l'occurence google.com
    """
    webbrowser.open_new("google.com")


def twitter():
    webbrowser.open_new("twitter.com")


def spotify():
    webbrowser.open_new("spotify.com")


def amazon():
    webbrowser.open_new("amazon.fr")


def netflix():
    webbrowser.open_new("netflix.fr")


def youtube():
    webbrowser.open_new("youtube.com")


def power_function():
    sys.exit()


# bouton esthétiuque pour faciliter la fermeture de l'interface tel un smartphone que l'on éteint en appuyant sur bouton
photo_onoff = PhotoImage(file="icons 2/power button icon.png")
button_onoff = Button(image=photo_onoff, command=power_function, borderwidth=0, bg="black")

# affichage du bouton etteindre via la fonction pack du module tkinter
button_onoff.pack(side=BOTTOM)

photo_twitter = PhotoImage(file="icons 2/twitter icon.png")
photo_spotify = PhotoImage(file=r"icons 2/spotify icon.png")
photo_youtube = PhotoImage(file="icons 2/YouTube_icon.png")
photo_amazon = PhotoImage(file="icons 2/amazon-black-icon-16.png")
photo_google = PhotoImage(file="icons 2/google icon.png")
photo_netflix = PhotoImage(file="icons 2/Netflix_icon.png")

# bouton des principales applications les plus utlisées reliés aux fonctions par le paramètre command
button_google = Button(image=photo_google, command=google, borderwidth=0)
button_youtube = Button(image=photo_youtube, command=youtube, borderwidth=0)
button_spotify = Button(image=photo_spotify, command=spotify, borderwidth=0)
button_twitter = Button(image=photo_twitter, command=twitter, borderwidth=0)
button_amazon = Button(image=photo_amazon, command=amazon, borderwidth=0)
button_netflix = Button(image=photo_netflix, command=netflix, borderwidth=0)

# affichage des différents boutons via la méthode pack()
button_twitter.pack()
button_spotify.pack()
button_amazon.pack()
button_google.pack()
button_netflix.pack()
button_youtube.pack()

# affichage de l'interface dans une boucle (l'interface est afficher jusqu'à l'arrêt de programme)
interface.mainloop()
```

Comment: If you want a background image and to be able to move the buttons, I'd suggest that you look at the tkinter canvas widget. You can use the `create_image` method to add the background and then the `create_window` to place widgets such as buttons.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. For create_image it works, to place button i've tried button.place and it works also :)